# d3.js using brush.clear() doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, d3.js, brush

In an object I store line chart made with d3.js, which have possibility to brush selected area.

Selected area is removed when I click outside selected part of line chart.

I'd like to remove selected area clicking on external link eg. [reset]

Unfortunately even if I access brush object from line chart object calling `clear()` on `brush` object doesn't remove selection.

How can I remove brush selection using external link from outside line chart?

I create brush:

```
this.brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(xScale)
    .on('brushstart', function() {
        lineChart.brushStart();
    })
    .on('brushend', function() {
        lineChart.brushEnd();
    });
```

I create brushing area:

```
this.brushArea = svg.append('svg:g')
    .attr('class', 'brush')
    .call(this.brush)
    .selectAll('rect')
    .attr('height', this.height);
```

On external link I put `clear()` command:

```
<span onclick="javascript: lineChart.brush.clear();">[reset]</span>
```

It doesn't remove selection from line chart.

Please help.

Documentation about `brush.clear()` is not efficient.

Answer (score 10):

From the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush_extent),

> Note that this does not automatically redraw the brush or dispatch any
>   events to listeners. To redraw the brush, call brush on a selection or
>   transition; to dispatch events, use brush.event.

You can achieve this by first clearing the brush and then redrawing it.

```
d3.selectAll(".brush").call(brush.clear());
```

This first clears the brush and redraws **all** the brushes on your page.

Although, I always recommend doing `clear()` on selections in context with their parent containers. For example:

```
d3.selectAll(".brush-container .brush").call(brush.clear());
```

The use case is when you've multiple brushes on your page.

Now to specifically answer your question, you can call a function like this

```
var d3Brush = this.brush;

function clearBrush(){
  d3.selectAll("g.brush").call(d3Brush.clear());
}
```

And call

```
<span onclick="javascript: clearBrush();">[reset]</span>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
brush.clear();
svg.selectAll('.brush').call(brush);
```

The second line is to redraw the brush.

Answer (score 5):

`brush.clear()` only resets the extent. You need to call `brush` again to redraw the brush. The documentation for [brush.extent](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-brush_extent) has some details about this.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to call `brush.event()` to make sure your listeners are fired. In d3.v3 it would look like this:

```
this.brushArea.call( this.brush.clear());
this.brush.event(this.brushArea);
```